Why does transparency have no effect in WezTerm terminal emulator?
Vim in WezTerm has no transparent effect. I set:
set termguicolors
hi Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight Nontext ctermbg=NONE
hi Normal guibg=NONE

It does not change anything, it is showing pure black.

And in other terminal emulators? Also: Where do you put those commands? What colorscheme do you use? Etc.
